# Parsed query contains no qtextpre in ML9

Tags: marklogic, cts-search

I've inherited code that was ported from ML7 to ML9 last year and the facet pane of a search page does not display a facet clear control like it did in the legacy system.  The XQuery logic to build the control depends on the result of `search:parse()` containing a `@qtextpre` attribute.  In the older system, the parsed query is:

```
<cts:element-range-query qtextpre="Status:" qtextref="cts:annotation" operator="=" xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <cts:element xmlns:_1="http://www.marklogic.com/ps/ns/qanda/">_1:Status</cts:element>
 <cts:annotation qtextref="following-sibling::cts:value"></cts:annotation>
 <cts:value xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Review</cts:value>
 <cts:option>collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint</cts:option>
</cts:element-range-query>
```

But in the new system the same query text with the same options parses to:

```
<cts:element-range-query operator="=" xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
 <cts:element xmlns:_1="http://www.marklogic.com/ps/ns/qanda/">_1:Status</cts:element>
 <cts:value xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Review</cts:value>
 <cts:option>collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint</cts:option>
</cts:element-range-query>
```

I'm not real clear on what that attribute is for, but this application code depends on finding the `@qtextpre` attribute in the query to decide whether to display the facet clear control in the facet pane.  Can anyone explain why it's not there in the ML9 version of the parsed query?

Comment: Actually, I get a different result from a simple call: search:parse("test").  In the ML7 system this gives a result with cts:word-query/@qtextref, but in the ML9 system the resulting cts:word has no @qtextref attribute.  If I can understand why this behavior is different, maybe I can figure out how to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to the documentation per Marklogic version for usage of the [`search:parse()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/9.0/search:parse) function.

I don't have an answer to why - the actual question you are asking, but I can answer the question: what is different in the latest 2 versions. That sounds like it would be more helpful...

In version 9 of the documentation, there is an option to get output in what is referred to as  `cts:annotated-query` format as well as `cts:query` format. It appears that the default is just less verbose. This was deprecated according to the notes, but available in the latest release of 9. With MarkLogic 9 having many changes to search, I am not sure which point release things may have changed. However, I believe that the `cts:annotated-query` option is will give the results you wish.

https://docs.marklogic.com/9.0/search:parse

> cts:annotated-query: Equivalent to the output produced by schema-element(cts:query), but with the addition of annotations. THIS FORM IS DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future release.

```
search:parse($qText, $options, "cts:annotated-query")
```

Please note that the docs for MarkLogic 10 also list the option you need as deprecated. So keep a lookout for needing a code change for your feature when you go from 9 to 10 of the options is removed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out David!  That $output parameter is exactly what I need.  This app really needs to be redesigned from the ground up, so hopefully that will happen before the annotated output feature goes away.